# How to reference Pivot Table's summary field from outside this table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

i.e. I need to make a cell in worksheet show the same value, as summary of my Pivot Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can just click into the cell in the pivot table you want to summarize.  For a grand total it should generate a formula that looks like this:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("data values",Sheet2!$A$1)
```

This assumes the field you're summarizing is called "data values" and that the top left cell of the pivot table is located at Sheet2!$A$1.

If this type of formula isn't automatically generated, you need to activate the "Generate GetPivotData" feature.  See this [Contextures](http://www.contextures.com/xlpivot06.html#GetPivotData) page for instructions.

GetPivotData is more complex if you are summarizing subtotals or individual items.  You can use variables in the formulas, which makes it quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

In the formula bar,

```
=<cell number of the Pivot table summary>
```

Comment: Bad idea. Summary is at the bottom, and table has variable count of rows

Comment: you need to be more specific then what exactly your requirements are and how your data is structured.

Comment: What exactly info you miss?